# Google wallet for digital goods, error while calling buy() function

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using google wallet for digital goods using javascript and google app engine. When my app calls the buy() function, I momentarilly see the expected screen in the demo, but then it times out and gives an error message.  The message is `Uh oh. There was a problem.  We couldn't start your purchase because of a technical issue. Details of the problem below: There is an error in the setup for your purchase. Please contact the merchant about this issue.`
Can anyone give me a clue as to where the problem stems from?

Comment: what are you trying to do? how are you trying to do it? are you trying one of the sample apps provided in the docs? rule: if the first comment has more than 1 question, then you should have posted more details about your problem (tl;dr version: show us some code and more context etc)

Comment: anyway, it seems to be an internal problem (and not related to you only). Found a google group post where they suggest to wait 24h and try again and in case, contact them here https://support.google.com/wallet/bin/request.py?hl=en&contact_type=contact_policy&contact_type=contact_policy&policy=wallet&rd=1

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo did you ever figure this out? I've got the same issue going on now.